# Check if an external application is running using wxWidgets

Tags: c++, cocoa, wxwidgets

I am looking for some `wxWidgets` function to check if an external application is running in the system. Something similar to `NSRunningApplications` in Cocoa.
I looked at a lot of wxwidgets apis including wxProcess class but didn't find a way to do this. 
Does anybody know a way to check if an external process is running in `wxWidgets` based on its name or application identifier (not pid).

Comment: For what it's worth, I also don't think that you can achieve what you need by using wxWidgets API only. But you can create platform-specific implementations for all the platforms you need. Probably doable in less than 50 lines of code per platform.

Comment: Yes, I guess I will have to consider that option. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way of checking external processes other than using the pid in wxWidgets.

The only ways of checking existence are for a process you have started yourself yourself using wxExecute / wxProcess or using the static function [wxProcess::Exists(int pid)](http://docs.wxwidgets.org/trunk/classwx_process.html#a3c81aa4ef5b6b76018e245f0b004f51b) to check for a running process with a given pid.

Comment: If you read the question, you will notice it was about finding a running process "based on its name or application identifier (**not** pid)". Therefore it's not particularly helpful to answer how to find a process by its pid.

Comment: Sorry, I completely missed that when I read the question, will edit.

Comment: Thanks for the response, Steve. Though, I would wait to get any other idea or approach from some other people before closing this question.